# Multi-slit interference

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, geometric-optics, interference

In an article related to multi-slits interference, the displacements of oscillating waves originating from different slits that meet each other in the detector are written as follows:

[image]

According to the article, δ is: the difference in the paths of rays passing through two consecutive slits.

I cannot understand why it is written like that. Also, why the time part is not included here for the waves.

Comment: Which article? Which page?

Comment: That looks like an approximation (Frauenhofer?) to me. I think it would be exact for the phases of a plane wave hitting a grating, which can be achieved with suitable optics. High precision spectrographs are trying to achieve such a phase relationship, if I am not mistaken (that's just some handwaving I am doing in my head, right now). See https://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach//education/senior/astrophysics/images/spectra/spectrographschematic.gif for the light path of such an instrument.

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard calculation that you'll find in any optic book studying diffraction gratings. In a nutshell:

The wave starting from slit number 0 can be written as:
$$s_0(x,t)=Ae^{i(\omega t-kx)}$$
From there let's assume that all those waves have the same amplitude $A$. And since $e^{i\omega t}$ will factor out and vanish when we take the squared modulus later on, I won't write it from now on.

Taking this wave number 0 as a reference, let $\delta$ be the *additional* optical distance traveled by wave number 1. It'll be zero if both waves are perpendicular to the diffraction grating, nonzero otherwise. So:
$$s_1(x,t)=Ae^{ik(x+\delta)}=s_0(x,t)e^{ik\delta}$$

Assuming all slits are equally spaced, you can repeat the process:
$$s_2(x,t)=s_1(x,t)e^{ik\delta}=s_0(x,t)e^{i2\delta}=Ae^{i(k+2\delta)}$$
and so on until the $n$-th slit (number $n-1$).